# How to prevent codeigniter from inserting space in regular expression

Tags: regex, codeigniter

How can i prevent codeigniter from inserting space in regular expression. Because when it did, it break the query.

for example I had a query that is using a regular expression interval but when codeigniter creates the sql, it inserts a space in the regular expression interval that break the query.
Basically codeigniter inserts a space in regular expression that breaks my query

My codeigniter code

```
$query = $this->db->select("@a:=@a+1 sno, t.trainingID, trgDescName, totalParticipants, (SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{12}[13579]$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `males`, (SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{12}[24680]$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `females`, (SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{0,12}$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `invalid cnic`, districtName, projectName, concat_ws(' ', fromDate, toDate) as dates , venue ", FALSE)
->join('trg_desc as td', 't.trgDescID = td.trgDescID', 'left')
->join('project as pj', 't.projectID = pj.projectID', 'left')
->join('training_district as tdi', 't.trainingID = tdi.trainingID', 'left')
->limit(20, 0)
->get('training as t');
```

for which codeigniter creates the following code that throws an error
Got error 'invalid repetition count(s)' from regexp

```
select  @a:=@a+1 sno, t.trainingID, trgDescName, totalParticipants, 
(SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{12}[13579]$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `males`,
(SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{12}[24680]$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `females`, 
(SELECT count(cnic) FROM participant WHERE cnic regexp '^[0-9]{0, 12}$' and `trainingID` = t.trainingID) as `invalid cnic`, 
districtName, projectName, concat_ws(" ", fromDate, toDate) as dates , venue
from training as t
left join trg_desc as td on t.trgDescID = td.trgDescID
left join project as pj on t.projectID = pj.projectID
left join training_district as tdi on t.trainingID = tdi.trainingID
limit 0, 20;
```

Can there is a way to prevent codeigniter to insert space ?

Comment: Basically I need 
    '^[0-9]{0,12}$' where as codeigniter creates 
    '^[0-9]{0, 12}$'
just this one space breaks the query
@Narf Well late night at 3 in the mourning I just got fed up and also though in the same lines but still post this question that just maybe their is a way and anyway through this will learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way - don't use the query builder.

You gain literally nothing from using it for queries like the one you've shown. You're practically writing all the SQL yourself *and* there's no way that query would work in the same way on another RDBMS, which is the whole point of using the query builder - portability.